# Flatten object with counts of each element

Tags: javascript, object

I am looking to flatten an object of this kind (in javascript):

```
{0: {State: true, Name: 'bob'},
1: {State: true, Name: 'candice'},
2: {State: true, Name: 'allen'},
3: {State: true, Name: 'bob'},
4: {State: true, Name: 'bob'},
5: {State: true, Name: 'candice'}
}
```

to an object like this:

```
{0: {Name: 'bob', Count: 3},
1: {Name: 'candice', Count: 2},
2: {Name: 'allen', Count: 1}
}
```

What's the cleanest solution to this problem?

Comment: This is not an array. It is an object

Comment: If this was an array, you could use Array.reduce, which would be the proper way

Comment: Sorry, object!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all that is an object, not an array.

The following code gets what you want:

```js
let obj = {
    0: { State: true, Name: 'bob' },
    1: { State: true, Name: 'candice' },
    2: { State: true, Name: 'allen' },
    3: { State: true, Name: 'bob' },
    4: { State: true, Name: 'bob' },
    5: { State: true, Name: 'candice' }
}
let grouped = {};
for (let val of Object.values(obj))
    grouped[val.Name] = (grouped[val.Name] ?? 0) + 1;

let entries = Object.entries(grouped);
let final = {};
for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
    final[i] = { Name: entries[i][0], Count: entries[i][1] }
    
console.log(final)
```

Comment: upvote for nice and clean  procedural programming instead of the usual reduce bullshit.